# Можно ли поставить иконки рядом с элементами "li", используя псевдоэлемент "before"?

Tags: css, css3

Можно ли поставить иконки рядом с элементами "li", используя псевдоэлемент "before"? 
content: url(image.jpg) помогает? но иконки огромные, а поменять никак не получается, даже задавая width/height.

Comment: когда то я тоже бился с этим вопросом .... но получил ответ спустя года только..... хоть и deprecated но однако других способов я не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Ну разумеется что это самый топорный метод из всех топорных методов но однако он работает ,смотрите

> оригинал изображения : https://www.cyldigital.es/sites/default/files/article/house.jpg

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li p{
  position: relative;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  zoom:.5;
}

li p:after{
  content:url(https://www.cyldigital.es/sites/default/files/article/house.jpg );
 zoom:.1;
}

li span{
  margin-left:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
li p{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=""> 
      <p></p>
      <span>Вернуться домой</span>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ура мой профиль удалили ....всем пока

Answer (score 0):

Все картинки в примере имеют размер 160х120 px. Как видите, они прекрасно добавляются и масштабируются:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px dotted #00f;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
}

li:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ff9999/444444) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}
li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/00CED1/444444) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/CE00D1/444444) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
}
li:last-child::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/CED100/444444) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>000</li>
  <li>111</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>333</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А чтобы у иконки были разными, тут li:nth-child:before не поможет вроде, не так ли?

Comment: @YersultanAshirbek поможет. Обновил пример.